# mocha command giving ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, jsdom

I am using command:

```
mocha --compilers :./test/babel-setup.js --recursive --watch
```

It is giving error:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

I have the following in my babel-setup.js:

```
require("babel/register")({
  compact: false
});
```

I am using node 0.12.7 and "mocha": "^2.2.5" and "jsdom": "^3.1.2".

I already have **jsdom** installed with the project.

What is causing the error?

Comment: what is in the "babel/register" file?

Comment: look like it is there for jsx support

Answer (score 97):

I was able to use [`jsdom-global`](https://github.com/rstacruz/jsdom-global) to fix this issue.  Follow the instructions in that link to install.  Specifically, run

```
npm install --save-dev --save-exact jsdom jsdom-global
```

then add `-r jsdom-global/register` to your mocha command-line.  When you re-run your tests, the `window is not defined` error will go away.

Comment: should be marked as an answer, works like a charm, thanks :)

Comment: For yarn, use `yarn add jsdom jsdom-global -DE`

Comment: Where exactly do you "add -r jsdom-global/register to your mocha command-line"? Sorry, I am a total noob at this.

Comment: It doesn't work if you are trying to use localStorage

Answer (score 2):

To test frontend libraries with mocha you need the node modul *mocha-jsdom* you find it here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-jsdom

Comment: i looked into that package it is not supporting node 0.12.7 and requires io.js

Comment: oh, i'm sorry for that. We use Node 4.0.0. Is an update not being considered for you?

Comment: actually it's deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Since I was doing too much with the window object, I just used this code to determine if I was in mocha or not.

```
function isMocha(){
    let context = (global || window);
    return ['afterEach','after','beforeEach','before','describe','it'].every(function(functionName){
        return context[functionName] instanceof Function;
    });
}
```